# Handling a specific route with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that users are being directed to from links in an email. Users are visiting one of the following links:

```
http://my-site.com/view-name
http://my-site.com/#/view-name
```

The only difference between the two is the addition of the '#'. I need both of these URLs to return the same view. How do I do that in ASP.NET MVC 4. This is a one-off situation. For that reason, I'm trying to figure out the quickest solution.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple routes patterns in route config file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultRoute1",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultRoute2",
            url: "{controller}/#/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

http:// localhost/Home/Index

http:// localhost/Home/#/Index

both returns same view.

Comment: What if I need to setup a route to `http://localhost/#/Home/Index`? (notice the hash is before the controller name. Not after. If I use  `"#/{controller}/{id}"` for the URL structure, I get a 403 error. Please note, my site is a child site of another site.

Comment: MVC 5 supports attribute routing at controller/action method level,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774807/Attribute-Routing-in-ASP-NET-MVC-WebAPI

if you're using MVC 5 then you can prefix "#" sign on controller level

i.e.
[RoutePrefix("#/Home")]

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not being specific enough. When I start my app in Visual Studio, `http://localhost/my-project-name/home` gets loaded. The reason my-project-name is included is because this project will the the child of a another app (out of my hands). In IE 9, when I visit that URL, I am redirected to `http://localhost/#/my-project-name/home (notice the hash location). From what I can tell the RoutePrefix won't work because the hash is added one layer up. That is why I need a way to read the route and return a specific view. Is there a way to do that?